# Set a delay on System.exit(0)

Tags: java, time, system, delay

I have the code below, however I want it in a function to be run 5 seconds after a System.out.println statement for examples

```
System.out.println("Well done");
//***5 second delay***
System.exit(0);`
```

How do I go about creating that 5 second delay between the println and the exit?

Comment: Anything wrong with `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)`? More to the point is _why_ you'd want to do this? There is very rarely a good reason to call `System.exit`.

Comment: You should train your searching skills. First link for "java pause" gives you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html which points you to `Thread.sleep(5000)` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Well done");
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.exit(0);`
```

Or to be little more specific, you can use the [`TimeUnit#sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long)) method on [`TimeUnit.SECONDS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#SECONDS):

```
System.out.println("Well done");
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
System.exit(0);`
```

On another note, this information is trivial to find through google. The search term "java pause" or "java sleep" throws up a number of links that are relevant to your question.